# How to stay in the same message after loading more messages in React chat component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, scroll, infinite-scroll

I have a React chat application where if I scroll to the very top of the list of messages, I initiate another call to fetch more messages. This is working fine but I'm having issues with scrolling.

Basically the container that holds the messages is defined as:

```html
<div
  className='flex flex-col w-full h-full pr-1 justify-between overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll'
  onScroll={handleScroll}>
  <div id='messages' className='flex flex-col grow space-y-4 py-3'>
    {isFetchingData && (
      <div className='flex justify-center items-center'>
        <Spinner size='md' />
      </div>
    )}
    {messages &&
      messages.length > 0 &&
      messages.map((msg) => {
        return (
          <ChatMessage
            key={msg.$id}
            room={room}
            message={msg}
            scrollToBottom={scrollToBottom}
          />
        );
      })}
    <div className='!m-0 !p-0' ref={messagesEndRef} />
  </div>
</div>
```

I also have a `useEffect` for when the `messages` state changes:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (shouldScroll) {
    scrollToBottom();
  }

  if (!isMessagesLoading) { // isMessagesLoading only refers to the initial fetch and not the proceeding ones
    setShouldScroll(false);
  }
}, [messages]);
```

Anyway, all of these work just fine - my problem is when I scroll all the way to the top of the container and I get new messages, the container stays on top, this is jarring because the user loses context on where they were. When new messages get added on top, I want the user to stay on the same message they were on before the fetching started.

Comment: https://github.com/vytenisu/use-chat-scroll

Comment: It would have been really helpful if we could have a working Codesandbox or something, using a dummy API like JSON Placeholder?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar I'll see if I can create one later after work